# Echo verabllees from database in php

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to echo out some variable in my database.

I have a table called channel and within that table there is  a row called cookie_script. How do I echo out the verbal in the cookie_script row variables that are stored in the db.

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Probably the best spelling of the word 'variable' I've ever seen.

Comment: `cookie_script` is a row or column? I assume `verbal` is also a typo for `value` or is there an audible form in the column/row?

Answer (score 1):

PDO is the recommended way of communicating with your database in PHP.

First you need to setup the connection:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'example';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

Now you can run queries on your database:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM cookie_script');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    print_r($row) . "\n";
}
```